# Call WebForm on window.onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms, dom-events

I want to call the "WebForm.aspx" on Javascript;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
      var msg = 'Are you sure?';
      e = e || window.event;

      if (e)
          e.returnValue = msg;

      return msg;
  }
```

The code return a message when the page is unload. Instead of returning a message I want to open the target web form..

Any Comment is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think I Got it already

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
      var msg = 'Are you sure?';
      e = e || window.event;

      if (e)
      window.showModalDialog('WebForm2.aspx');

  }
```

thanks